# (Java) How to get current date in YY.MM.DD form?

Tags: java, string, date

I would like to store the current date in YY.MM.DD (separated by periods, if that's possible) into a string. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Take a look at simpledateformat, that may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) like this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // The format.
  DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yy.MM.dd");
  Date theDate = new Date(); // a date.
  String dateStr = sdf.format(theDate); // to a String. dateStr for example.
  System.out.println(dateStr); // Print it out.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yy.MM.dd");
String date = sdf.format(new Date());
```

Here are all the possible options:

[image]

Please refer to the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) API for more info. Here's the [1.7 options list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), if you prefer.

Comment: D should be lowercase, because a capital d means day in the year, not day in the month. And y should technically be lowercase (even though it doesn't have to)

Comment: @MistressDavid I think it does not matter if y is capital or small,run   the codes using yy or YY and see the output But I agree with you that d should be small

Comment: Yep, missed that. Rushed for the first answer. :D Thanks. @MistressDavid

Comment: @JqueryLearner Actually YY will cause a parsing error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat sim=new SimpleDateFormat("YY.MM.dd");
    Date d1=new Date();
System.out.println(sim.format(d1));
```

**Output** 13.12.07

[image]

Comment: Buddy: YY gives this error: Illegal pattern character 'Y'

Comment: @Jops It does not give me any error.I have just run the code and pasted here.Did you try with my code or shall I attach a screen shot?

Comment: Using my code, YY did give the exception.

Comment: @Jops Please see the screenshot,

Comment: @Jops I dont know why it gives you error but It does not give any.hence I have attached a screenshot

Comment: JDK version. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html vs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42692/discussion-between-jquerylearner-and-jops)

Comment: @Jops yes i did and still no error at all.The parse exception was for my previous codes.For trying OP's requirement,I had deleted the existing codes from main and wrote new codes but forgot to remove parseexception

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yy.MM.dd");
String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
```

Comment: D should be lowercase, because capital d means day in the year ( like 186)